# Selecting elements between two text values on a webpage using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape text values from a [Website](http://www.thegoodscentscompany.com/data/rw1023571.html#tosynm). I am interested in the **synonyms** **section** however the tags used are also used throughout the website for other sections.

I am currently trying to get elements that are below "Synonyms:" and above "Articles" as this is the only way i think i can isolate this section

```
synsection = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("*[following::div[text()='Synonyms:'] and preceding::div[text()='Articles:']]")
```

Can anyone help me isolate the section to pull the synonyms text.

I'm using selenium (python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need it in a tabular form where each line is a df row, you can use the below two lines:-

```
import pandas as pd

page = 'http://www.thegoodscentscompany.com/data/rw1023571.html#tosynm'

df = pd.read_html(page)[-2]
```